# Cargar imagen de carpeta resources maven

Tags: java, maven

¿Como puedo cargar en java una imagen que se encuentra en la carpeta resources/static/images de la estructura de archivos de maven?

```
private Image damelogoEmpresa() { Image imagen= null; try { imagen = Image.getInstance("/home/alumno/Imágenes/logoAlbaran.jpg"); imagen.setAbsolutePosition(40, 650f); imagen.setAlignment(Image.LEFT | Image.TEXTWRAP); imagen.scalePercent(30f); imagen.setIndentationLeft(40f); } catch (BadElementException | IOException e) { logger.info("Error al obtener imagen logo albaran."); System.err.println("Error al leer la imagen"); } return imagen; }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cargar imágen con maven da NPE ( Couldn't find file )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273988/cargar-im%c3%a1gen-con-maven-da-npe-couldnt-find-file)

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del ciclo de vida de Maven mas concretamente en la fase Package, Maven copia todos los archivos de la carpeta resources a target/classes, asi que debes poder acceder a las imagenes utilizando el Path relativo 'static/images/logo.jpg'.

Comment: No es posible. El proyecto lo estoy desarrollando con spring boot y necesito instanciar una imagen para usarla con la libreria itextpdf. El caso es que necesito proporcionarle la ruta de la imagen y no encuentro la forma.

Comment: private Image damelogoEmpresa() {
  
  Image imagen= null;

  try {
   
   imagen = Image.getInstance("/home/alumno/Imágenes/logoAlbaran.jpg");
   imagen.setAbsolutePosition(40, 650f);
   imagen.setAlignment(Image.LEFT | Image.TEXTWRAP);
   imagen.scalePercent(30f);
   imagen.setIndentationLeft(40f);
  
  } 
     catch (BadElementException | IOException e) {
      logger.info("Error al obtener imagen logo albaran.");
      System.err.println("Error al leer la imagen"); 
  } 
  return imagen;
 }

Comment: @berni10 aunque creas que no es posible, él sigue teniendo razón.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para cargar imágenes desde esa carpeta puedes hacerlo directamente desde la vista usando thymeleaf. Un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/gest-MAT.jpg}" style="text-align: right; width: 305px"
hspace="16" height="190"  vspace="1" align="right">
```

Espero que te ayude, saludos!