# Cargar imágen con maven da NPE ( Couldn't find file )

Tags: java, archivo, maven

estoy intentando crear un icono en Java con ImageIcon, pero no consigo que encuentre la ruta que le estoy pasando. Os pongo el fragmento de código y el árbol de directorios del proyecto.

El Fragmento de código lo estoy ejecutando en Casilla.java, que está dentro del directorio

> ./src/main/java/smma/juegosTablero/gui

Fragmento de código:

```
    private final ImageIcon water = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/contents/water.jpg"));
```

Árbol de directorios (lo más importante):

> ```
> Directorio principal:
> data/
> src/
> target/
>
> Directorios secundarios:
> ./src:
> main/
> test/
>
> ./src/main:
> java/
> resources/
>
> ./src/main/java:
> smma/
>
> ./src/main/java/smma:
> juegosTablero/
>
> ./src/main/java/smma/juegosTablero:
> agentes/
> contents/
> gui/
> util/
>
> ./src/main/java/smma/juegosTablero/contents:
> acorazado1_3.jpeg
> acorazado2_3.jpg
> acorazado3_3.jpg
> destructor1_2.jpg
> destructor2_2.jpeg
> fragata1_1.jpg
> portaaviones1_4.jpeg
> portaaviones2_4.jpeg
> portaaviones3_4.jpg
> portaaviones4_4.jpeg
> t_acorazado1_3.jpg
> t_acorazado2_3.jpg
> t_acorazado3_3.jpg
> t_destructor1_2.jpg
> t_destructor2_2.jpg
> t_fragata1_1.jpg
> t_portaaviones1_4.jpg
> t_portaaviones2_4.jpg
> t_portaaviones3_4.jpg
> t_portaaviones4_4.jpg
> water.jpg
>
> ./src/main/java/smma/juegosTablero/gui:
> Advertencia.form
> Advertencia.java
> AgentesJuegoJFrame.form*
> AgentesJuegoJFrame.java*
> Casilla.java
> ClasificacionJuegoJFrame.form*
> ClasificacionJuegoJFrame.java*
> Consola.form*
> Consola.java*
> Final.form
> Final.java
> JuegosTableroJFrame.form*
> JuegosTableroJFrame.java*
> OkCancelDialog.form*
> OkCancelDialog.java*
> PanelFicha.java
> PoolDeFichas.java
> Tablero.form
> Tablero.java
> Tablerom.java
> ```

¿Dónde tendría que colocar la carpeta "contents" dentro del árbol anterior para que me reconozca la ruta? Es que me estoy volviendo loco.

### Intentos

He estado haciendo pruebas para ver por qué no se encuentra la ruta y he hecho esta función para ver la ruta del directorio actual:

```
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path + " en:" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Y llamo a esta función así:

```
private final ImageIcon water = createImageIcon("/contents/water.jpg");
```

Y me da la siguiente salida por consola:

> Couldn't find file: /contents/water.jpg
>   en:/Users/joseangel/Downloads/JuegosTablero-1.0.1

Y el nuevo árbol del directorio es:

> ```
> Directorio Principal (JuegosTablero-1.0.1)
>
> contents/
> data/
> src/
> target/
>
> ./contents:
> acorazado1_3.jpeg
> acorazado2_3.jpg
> acorazado3_3.jpg
> destructor1_2.jpg
> destructor2_2.jpeg
> fragata1_1.jpg
> portaaviones1_4.jpeg
> portaaviones2_4.jpeg
> portaaviones3_4.jpg
> portaaviones4_4.jpeg
> t_acorazado1_3.jpg
> t_acorazado2_3.jpg
> t_acorazado3_3.jpg
> t_destructor1_2.jpg
> t_destructor2_2.jpg
> t_fragata1_1.jpg
> t_portaaviones1_4.jpg
> t_portaaviones2_4.jpg
> t_portaaviones3_4.jpg
> t_portaaviones4_4.jpg
> water.jpg
>
> ./data:
> juegos.dat
>
> ./src:
> main/
> test/
>
> ./src/main:
> java/
> resources/
>
> ./src/main/java:
> smma/
>
> ./src/main/java/smma:
> juegosTablero/
>
> ./src/main/java/smma/juegosTablero:
> Constantes.java*
> Fichero.pdf
> agentes/
> gui/
> util/
>
> ./src/main/java/smma/juegosTablero/gui:
> Advertencia.form
> Advertencia.java
> AgentesJuegoJFrame.form*
> AgentesJuegoJFrame.java*
> Casilla.java
> ClasificacionJuegoJFrame.form*
> ClasificacionJuegoJFrame.java*
> Consola.form*
> Consola.java*
> Final.form
> Final.java
> JuegosTableroJFrame.form*
> JuegosTableroJFrame.java*
> OkCancelDialog.form*
> OkCancelDialog.java*
> PanelFicha.java
> PoolDeFichas.java
> Tablero.form
> Tablero.java
> Tablerom.java
> ```

El caso es que se supone que el directorio actual es donde está la carpeta "contents" y no lo encuentra  ¿Qué puede ser?

### **Este es el pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pedroj</groupId>
    <artifactId>JuegosTablero</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository> 
            <id>tilab</id> 
            <url>https://jade.tilab.com/maven/</url> 
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.tilab.jade</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jade</artifactId> 
            <version>4.5.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.PedroJSanchez</groupId>
        <artifactId>Ontologias</artifactId>
        <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: ¿es solo java o usas algún framework como spring? ¿usas maven?

Comment: Ay.. se me olvidaba, estoy usando Jade, así que sí, uso maven.

Comment: ¿te falla desde el IDE o cuando lo usas fuera de el?

Comment: Desde el IDE, no sé cómo usarlo fuera de él...

Comment: desde fuera es correrlo mediante `java -jar miproyecto.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución ha sido mover la carpeta de imágenes al directorio raiz del proyecto y todo ha empezado a funcionar!

Gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Alfred.

Me parece que deberías colocar la carpeta contents dentro de src/main/resources
En un proyecto pequeño que he creado he colocado una clase **Main** como sigue:

```
package mx.net.alvatroz.ruta;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author alvaro
 */
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Este es un mensaje con un icono", "hola amigo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon( Main.class.getResource("/contents/monitor.jpg")));
   }
}
```

En mi estructura de carpetas tengo:

[image: Ruta de mi projecto]

Al ejecutar desde el IDE o invocando al Jar de mi proyecto tengo:

[image: ejemplo de ejecución]

Quedo atento a tus dudas o comentarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero he probado a meter ahí la carpeta de contents y sigue sin encontrar la ruta, es muy extraño, porque tengo otro proyecto parecido y he puesto la carpeta en el mismo sitio que en el otro proyecto y lo invoco de la misma forma y en el otro proyecto funciona y en este no, de ahí que me esté volviendo loco jajaja

Answer (score 2):

En el caso de los proyectos maven tienen lo que se llama [disposición estándard](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) de directorios, que es la forma en que los directorios vienen configurados por defecto.

En esta configuración debes agregar una carpeta de recursos y maven se encargará de ponerlos en tu classpath.

La carpeta de recursos si sigues la disposición estándard debe de hallarse en `./src/main/resources`. Esto te evitará muchos posibles problemas pues hará que funciona igual en tu IDE y al correr el jar generado.

[image: configuración de ruta]

En este caso he usado un borde que recibe un icono para pintarlo como imágen de fondo de mi JFrame mediante la siguiente línea

```
jPanel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/contents/water.jpg"))));
```

El resultado se vecomo habría de esperarse:

[image: JFrame con imágen de fondo]

En mi caso usé código personalizado desde el asistentevisual en el IDE [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) para prevenir que alguien novato llegue y modifique el código sin querer y sobre todo para tener en un miso lugar la lógica de interfaz y no juntarla con la lógica de negocio.

[image: código personalizado de Netbeans no editable]

Este proyecto de ejemplo lo puedes hallar en github ya que lo acabo de [subir](https://github.com/javatlacati/Java-ImageIcon-NullPointerException).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pongo la carpeta dentro de resources y tampoco me encuentra la ruta... Si quieres, te puedo enviar el proyecto por privado a ver si consigues encontrar dónde está el error, te explico cómo ejecutarlo para que veas el fallo. Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Tal vez debas de bajar el código fuente de la liga que te puse, seguramente con un ejemplo que corre será mejor.

Comment: He bajado el ejemplo, pero haciendo lo que haces en el ejemplo sigue sin funcionar... no entiendo por qué no encuentra la ruta. Es que miro y vuelvo a mirar y veo todo bien.

Comment: @Alfred entonces no puedo reproducir tu problema sin más información, tal vez deberías de agregar tu pom a la pregunta para verificar que no estés cambiando la ruta de `resources` por una personalizada

Comment: Acabo de añadir el pom a la pregunta, pero no cambio que yo sepa la ruta de resources.
Por eso te digo, que si quieres, te puedo pasar un enlace al proyecto y desde ahí, puedes verlo mejor.

Comment: Sí, sería bueno que postearas un enlace al proyecto en tu pregunta, si es en github mejor

Comment: Acabo de añadir el enlace al repositorio de Github en la pregunta. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Has encontrado algo? Para ver el error, tienes que ejecutarlo, te vas a la plataforma de gestión de agentes y en el contenedor main, creas un nuevo ageente de tipo AgentePruebaJuegador, y ya peta solo jajaja

Comment: has encontrado alguna solución? Yo llevo todo el día y nada...

Comment: En el pom no se ve nada. Reviso y te comento.

Comment: ¿cual es la clase con la que pruebas y te sale el error?

Comment: Favor de colocar el log o la salida en consola por que creo que el error no tiene nada que ver con eso de la carga de la imagen.

Comment: Ya he conseguido solucionarlo, el problema estaba en que no sé por qué, no encontraba la ruta, la solución ha sido meter la carpeta de imágenes en el directorio raiz del proyecto y de forma que no puedo explicar, lo ha encontrado y ya funciona!

Answer (score 1):

Tenia el mismo error, estoy usando openjdk 11 y netbeans 12, la unica solucion que encontré fue:

- Estableciendole la imagen yo mismo(no con la opcion de propiedades)
- Dándole una ruta mas completa con **`"src/main/java/packagedelaimagen/imagen.png"`**

Answer (score -1):

Se que el problema problema de MAVEN con carpetas sigue hasta ahora (Uso Apache Netbeans 17 - Maven, pero este video da la solución de forma exácta:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_9qrcVq7T4
Ojala les sirva... a mi me ayudó un montón

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/400266)