# Problema al ejecutar Splash Screen

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8.2, windows10

Buen día:

Estoy teniendo problemas al momento de ejecutar el código de un Splash Screen que vi en un tutorial de YouTube, Netbeans no lo muestra solo aparece el mensaje:

run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

alguien sabe a que puede deberse este error de que NO me muestra el splash? debo configurar algo para que se ejecute y lo muestre?
ya que quiero agregar un splash screen a mi proyecto de tesis, descargué varios proyectos de ejemplos y me muestra los splash screen sin problemas.

Desde ya gracias!

Estoy trabajando con Netbeans 8.2 en Windows 10.

Adjunto el código: **Este es el form**

```
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
*
* @author 
*/
public class inicio extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

 private Timer timer;
 
 int i=0;
 private int contador = 0;
 private String punto = ".";
 
 /**
  * Creates new form inicio
  */
     
 public inicio() {
     
  
   
   initComponents();
     setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes.splash/logo_parrilla.png")); 
     setIconImage(icon);
     jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/r22.png")));
 
     timer = new Timer(40,new ActionListener()
     {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o)
         {
             //contador
             i+=1;
             //al progresbar se le pasa como parametro el contador
             jProgressBar1.setValue(i);
             if(contador==45)
             {
                 punto = ".";
                 contador=0;
                 texto.setText("Cargando");
             }else{
                 punto +=".";
                 texto.setText("Cargando"+punto);
             }
             
             contador++;
             if(jProgressBar1.getValue()>20)
                 jProgressBar1.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);                
             
             if(jProgressBar1.getValue()>60)
                 jProgressBar1.setForeground(Color.BLUE); 
             
             //cuando llega a 100 pone un stop
             cek();
         }
     });
     timer.start();
   
   
 }
 
  //metodo para hacer que haga un stop antes de llegar a 100
 public void cek(){
     if(jProgressBar1.getPercentComplete()==1.0){
         timer.stop();            
         FrmLogin LG = new FrmLogin();
         LG.setVisible(true);
         //main.login();
         this.dispose();
     }        
 }       
 
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
 private void initComponents() {

     texto = new javax.swing.JLabel();
     jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
     jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

     setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

     texto.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
     texto.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
     texto.setText("Cargando componentes...");
     getContentPane().add(texto, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 400, 350, -1));
     getContentPane().add(jProgressBar1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 420, 350, 20));

     jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/splash/r22.png"))); // NOI18N
     getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(4, 4, 820, 510));

     pack();
 }// </editor-fold>                        

 /**
  * @param args the command line arguments
  */
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
     //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
     /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
      * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
      */
     try {
         for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
             if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                 javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                 break;
             }
         }
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     //</editor-fold>
     
     /* Create and display the form */
     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         
          inicio a;
          
         public void run() {
             
             a = new inicio();
             a.setVisible(true);
         }
     });
 }
 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 }

 // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
 private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
 private javax.swing.JLabel texto;
 // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Este es el java class**

```
package Controlador;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Splash {
    
     public Splash()
    {
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       /* inicio i = new inicio();
        i.setVisible(true); */
       
        new inicio().setVisible(true); 
    }
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" significa que compila sin problemas, no es un mensaje de error. Intenta mandar captura de tu icono de proyecto apra saber si es ant, maven, freeform, o web. Saludos.

Comment: no, de tu icono de proyecto

Comment: ok ahora agrega el icono de tu proyecto, no me interesa ver el contenido de ninguno de tus archivos, sino de tu raíz de proyecto. Creo que tu proyecto es de tipo maven pero no lo puedo confirmar sin ver tu estructura de carpetas o el icono de proyecto que le pon el IDE.

Comment: @RuslanLópez adjunté una nueva imagen...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cargar imágen con maven da NPE ( Couldn't find file )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273988/cargar-im%c3%a1gen-con-maven-da-npe-couldnt-find-file)

Comment: En particular [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/274087/342) debería de ser más que suficiente para resolver tu problema, en caso contrario comentanoslo.