# Añadir archivos a proyecto MAVEN

Tags: java, xml, java-swing, maven

Estoy haciendo un programa con SWING y le quiero introducir imágenes para iconos en la app. Al principio me funcionó pero ahora ya no me reconoce el directorio **src/main/resources** cuando cargo los archivos pero en sí me aparecen los archivos y me marca que esa ruta es un Source Folder.

---

Esta es mi estructura:

```
src
 |-main
    |-java
       |-PerreraXML
          |-retos
             |- PerreraXML
                 |- Frame.java
    |-resources
       |- images
           |- app_icon.png
```

---

Este es mi archivo java:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private Image app_icon = new ImageIcon(LoginFrame.class.getResource("/app_icon.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(60, 60, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        });
    }

    /**
    * Create the frame.
    */
    public Test() {
        setIconImage(app_icon);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
    
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(app_icon));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(73, 70, 66, 67);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel);
    }
}
```

---

Y esta parte es mi configuración del POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>retos</groupId>
  <artifactId>PerreraXMLARM</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>PerreraXMLARM</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target/src/main/resources</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                <include>**/*.png</include>
                <include>**/*.gif</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>         
    </resources>
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <index>true</index>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>retos.PerreraXMLARM.LoginFrame</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Maven Shade Plugin para empaquetar las dependencias con la aplicacion -->
            <!-- Es decir, en el archivo jar que generemos con package se almacenan las librerías que se necesiten -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Define cuando se ha de ejecutar el plugin -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>retos.PerreraXMLARM.LoginFrame</Main-Class>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

No me reconoce la imagen, ni ningun archivo que esté en resources ni en resources/images
¿Qué tengo mal? Es el tercer projecto maven que copio y pego el código y aun así...

Comment: ya intentaste quitarle el `/`?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si, he intentado algunas cosas que me encontré en por stackoverflow y nada...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cargar imágen con maven da NPE ( Couldn't find file )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273988/cargar-im%c3%a1gen-con-maven-da-npe-couldnt-find-file)

Comment: @RuslanLópez No, la verdad no. No entiendo por qué no encuentra el directorio src/main/resources para guardar ahi mis imagenes.

Comment: yo creo que funcionaría a la primera mediante `this.getClass().getResource("images/app_icon.png")` por las razones que explico en mi respuesta a la antes mencionada pregunta