# Hibernate no localiza archivo xml

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

realmente esta pregunta la debería hilar a la anterior que formulé ([Añadir archivos a proyecto MAVEN](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492512/a%C3%B1adir-archivos-a-proyecto-maven?noredirect=1#comment875362_492512)) pero como nadie la ha respondido aún pues añado otra más a la lista. Tengo mi proyecto y la sourceFolder de resources creada haciendo "src/main/resources", se supone que hibernate debe cogerla en esa ruta... Pero no es así.
Además en el archivo de configuracion del pom.xml tengo configurado como resource esa ruta, por qué sucede esto.

Os adjunto una imagen de referencia

[image: Fotografía del proyecto maven con archivo de configuracion de hibernate y archivo de configuracion de maven]

Comment: Hola Alex, comprueba si se encuentra ese fichero el de configuración cfg.xml en la ruta en la que te está especificando, es necesario entre otras cosas para establecer la conexión.

Comment: @SantiagoMrv Hola buenas, el archivo se encuentra en la ruta src/main/resources... si necesitas te puedo facilitar el ZIP con el proyecto...

Comment: Tal vez el nombre de la archivo  o la extensión está mal escrita, y por eso no encuentra el archivo en la ruta especificada.