# cargar imagen proyecto maven apache netbeans

Tags: java, maven, apache-netbeans

Hace poco cambie de utilizar Netbeans a Apache Netbeans 11.3. Además contruyo proyectos con maven, aunque tengo muy poca experiencia. El problema que tengo es que no me muestra las imágenes indicándome NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION. He visto bastantes escritos en stackoverflow y veo que a muchos
les ha ocurrido lo mismo. Voy a poner dos códigos, bastantes simples, que estoy probando y no me funcionan.

Código primero

```
    public class ProbarImagen_1 extends JFrame{
    //Ruta en el proyecto → src/main/resources/images/middle.gif
    private String img="/images/middle.gif";
    private ImageIcon imagen;
    
    public ProbarImagen_1(){
        setLayout(null);
        imagen = createImageIcon(img,"Mancha");
        add(new JLabel(imagen));
    }
    
    protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,String description) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = ProbarImagen_1.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        ProbarImagen_1 frame=new ProbarImagen_1();
        frame.setTitle("PruebaImagen");
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Código segundo

```
    public class ProbarImagen_3 extends JFrame{
    //Ruta en el proyecto → src/main/resources/images/middle.gif
    private String img="/images/middle.gif";
    private ImageIcon imagen;
    private JLabel label;
    
    public ProbarImagen_3(){
        imagen=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(img));
        label=new JLabel(imagen);
        add(label);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        ProbarImagen_3 frame=new ProbarImagen_3();
        frame.setTitle("PruebaImagen");
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Y también añado el pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject20</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

A ver si alguien me puede informar. Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Probaste con `private String img="/resources/images/middle.gif";`?

Comment: Gracias por responder. Si ya probé con todo y hoy he vuelto a probar.

Comment: según yo si es maven le sobra el / y debería ser resources/images/middle.gif

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cargar imágen con maven da NPE ( Couldn't find file )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273988/cargar-im%c3%a1gen-con-maven-da-npe-couldnt-find-file)

Answer (score 0):

Ya he resuelto el problema de cargar las imágenes. La diferencia estaba en que los códigos anteriormente indicado estaban en un proyecto que inicie en Apache Netbeans. Ahora la solución la he encontrado al crear un nuevo proyecto en línea de comandos. Entonces el pom ha sido diferente, y efectuvamente las imágenes van en un paquete de resource como ya estaban. Al compilar me ha copiado las imagenes en el directorio target. Considerando que no tengo mucha experiencia en maven, a día de hoy no puedo explicar en qué consiste esta diferencia. Un saludo a todos.

Comment: Finalmente resolver los proyectos creados directamente con el ide ApacheNetbeans para cargar las imagenes ha sido más fácil. Solo había, tras poner las imagenes en el directorio resources, utilizar el clean and compile. Un saludo